# Simulate the real World load runner scenario in Jmeter using stepping thread group

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, loadrunner

My client wants to simulate the Loadrunner scenario in Jmeter using the stepping thread group [image]

I have simulated the load in Jmeter with these parameters
[image]

. It is pulling wrong results can i know how to simulate the load correctly . Thankyou .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best place for asking others to do your job for you

Whatever:

The best way of ensuring that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing add [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener and compare its output with LoadRunner's charts for active VUsers.

Coming back to your question:

1. In LoadRunner the [ramp-up settings](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) are more "smooth"

   [image]

   and in your setup you're releasing next 50 users "chunk" at once
2. Once all users are started you need to hold the load for 1800 seconds and you have 150
3. The last line of LoadRunner's scenario assumes stopping 1 user each 6 seconds and you're stopping all at once after 1500 seconds

Example implementation:

[image]

Comment: I think i got it 

according to the above scenario since there is no delay the wait time is zero

then we are initializing 50 threads and each thread runs for 1 min  so 

 50 thread runs in 60*5 = 300 sec  and the ramp up period is also 300 seconds 

here i guess the duration is the ramp-up time ,

It is mentioned to hold the load for 30 min so 30*60 =1800 seconds .

and it is finally mentioned to stop 1 thread every 6 seconds . 


https://imgur.com/ZH1uWHr